# Android Launcher with KEYCODE_VOICE_ASSIST key capture

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-keypad, android-tv, nexus-player

I was wondering if that would be possible with a custom launcher as it seems [per the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_VOICE_ASSIST) that key code is not delivered to applications.

So when pressing the mic button on remote controls or keyboards that have it, how would an app or a custom launcher react like [Google's Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher&hl=en) that opens up the voice search command for instance (not that this is the action I would like triggered but just listen to the event of pressing the button and reacting accordingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `onSearchRequested()` in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    // return false if you just want to listen to the event
    // return true if you are overriding the system's functionality

}
```